# C# Task.WaitAll() in .Net and Mono

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, dns, mono

Why does this code behave different on Windows and Linux (using Mono)?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Task[] tasks = new Task[1];

    tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IPHostEntry iphe = Dns.GetHostEntry("8.8.8.8.dnsrbl.org");
    });
    Task.WaitAll(tasks, 2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Done in " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
}
```

`8.8.8.8.dnsrbl.ru` is an example of a query that will eventually time out. I believe there is no working DNS server (or its firewall is blocking me).

Anyway, the point is not getting a result from the DNS server, the point is how `Task.WaitAll()` behaves on Windows and Mono when waiting for a task containing a call to `Dns.GetHostEntry()`.

On Windows the program takes more or less 2 seconds to run when the query is not returning any result within the timeout period (2s). That is, Task.WaitAll with timeout seems to work. Running this program on Linux with Mono takes 2 seconds to get the output, but the program does not terminate until the task exits.  Why is that?

It seems like I get the same execution time regardless if I use Time.WaitAll with timeout or not.

The clue is in `Dns.GetHostEntry()` because `Task.WaitAll()` works as expected if I start a task with a `Thread.Sleep()` simulating a long running task.
This works as expected:

```
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
```

<strike>Is there a way to force `Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, int millisecondsTimeout)` to actually time out when running in Mono?</strike>

Edit: Task.WaitAll() does in fact return after the timeout period, but the program doesn't terminate when running in Mono (until `Dns.GetHostEntry` times out).

And it's not the compiler. I get the same result whether I compile with Visual Studio or the Mono C# compiler.

Comment: But you said that `Task.WaitAll` timeouts correctly even on mono (you got output in 2 seconds, which means Task.WaitAll returns in 2 seconds).

Comment: Yes, my bad. Sorry. The program seems to wait. I'll edit the question.

Comment: What if you remove `Task.WaitAll` and just start new task with `Dns.GetHostEntry` inside? Will that also hold program from completing?

Comment: Evk, when removing `Task.WaitAll` it completes immediately in both environments (as expected).

Comment: And what if you start new task, then put `Thread.Sleep(2000)` and exit?

Comment: Ah! That may be a workaround! It doesn't answer the question though, but a nice fix. Thanks!

Comment: Well I did not intend that to be a workaround :) Just trying to find the cause of the issue. So starting task, followed by Thread.Sleep(2000) causes program to exit immediately after sleep?

Comment: Opps! I was wrong. Replacing `Task.WaitAll(tasks, 2000)` with `Thread.Sleep(2000)` doesn't make any difference. Strange... `Thread.Sleep(10)` exits immediately but `Thread.Sleep(100)` takes 10 seconds to exit.

Comment: That means (most likely) that `Dns.GetHostEntry` on linux starts new non-background thread. Program cannot complete until all non-background threads are finished. Confirming this is hard, because `Dns.GetHostEntry` in mono ends up calling some native function which source code is hard to analyze (or even find).

Comment: I agree! And its a shame it works like that. A DNS-query is a 'fire-and-forget' action and should be terminated whenever the user wants to terminate. Dns.GetHostEntry doesn't even take a `CancellationToken`  :-(

Comment: Evk, thanks! I've answered my own question, but you are the hero. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll answer my own question although credit should go to Evk who guided me on the right track (thanks mate!)

The subject on this question is bad to say the least. The problem has nothing to do with `Task.WaitAll` but rather the Mono implementation of `Dns.GetHostEntry`. As Evk said in a comment:

> That means (most likely) that `Dns.GetHostEntry` on linux starts new
>   non-background thread. Program cannot complete until all
>   non-background threads are finished.

The `GetHostEntry()` method is located in the source file Dns.cs and when called with a string it calls `GetHostByName` which then calls `GetHostByName_internal` which is an external C function located in w32socket.c. Finally `mono_get_address_info` (in networking-posix.c) is called and we are down in the libc function `getaddrinfo`. Phew!

I cannot see any new non-background threads being started, but I found this:

```
MONO_ENTER_GC_SAFE;
ret = getaddrinfo (hostname, service_name, &hints, &info);
MONO_EXIT_GC_SAFE;
```

`MONO_ENTER_GC_SAFE` and `MONO_EXIT_GC_SAFE` are macros defined in mono-threads-api.h

```
#define MONO_ENTER_GC_SAFE  \
    do {    \
        gpointer __gc_safe_dummy;   \
        gpointer __gc_safe_cookie = mono_threads_enter_gc_safe_region (&__gc_safe_dummy)

#define MONO_EXIT_GC_SAFE   \
        mono_threads_exit_gc_safe_region (__gc_safe_cookie, &__gc_safe_dummy);  \
    } while (0)
```

I did not dig any further, but I believe Evk is right.

So, the answer to my question: `Dns.GetHostEntry()` cannot be terminated or cancelled in Mono. A program calling this method will not terminate until all queries has been processed or timed out. That’s the way it is. My guess is that is has to do with the garbage collector (GC) which probably runs in non-background thread and hence cannot be cancelled/terminated.

Edit: (A few days later) The reason for this was obvious once I got down to the man-page for `getaddrinfo`. This function returns a linked list to the result. This list is of course allocated on the heap, and has to be freed at some point to avoid memory leakage. The function for that is `freeaddrinfo`.

Anyway, thanks again to Evk!

So how can we fire multiple DNS queries in parallel with a timeout (using Mono)? Easy! This function can be called in a Task and it will be happy to obey WaitAll with timeout:

```
private static string host(string query)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("host", query);
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```