# How to P/Invoke getaddrinfo in Linux using Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm having problems with the structs and linked list when trying to use getaddrinfo from libc like this:

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6")]
private static extern int getaddrinfo(string node, string service,
                       addrinfo hints,
                       addrinfo res);
```

How can I make the missing `addrinfo` (and `sockaddr` inside `addrinfo`). `addrinfo` is a linked list by the way. I'm guessing I have to `[MarshalAs]` but I have no idea how to do that.

If you are thinking of suggesting `Dns.GetHostEntry`, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900338/c-sharp-task-waitall-in-net-and-mono). It's the reson why I plan to invoke `getaddrinfo` from libc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The short answer is “Don’t do it!” :-)

The reason is that `getaddrinfo` creates a linked list on the heap (the `res` pointer) and that needs to be freed.

It can be done however, with a disposable wrapper (adapter pattern), but it’s most likely to cause the same issues as `Dns.GetHostEntry` as described in the post linked in the question.